# Why SQL throws an error if I have a legal code the never will be reached?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I've got a very strange behavior with the below code.

```
--IMPORTANT: Do not use 'GO' since it will terminate
--the batch and it is only usable in Microsoft tools
--and not in the code itself.
--I don't really need a workaround I want to know why
--this behavior happens.

--Create the first time if doesn't exists

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NULL
    begin
        create table #temp (ID datetime)        
    end


--I've just created so it should evaluates as False
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NULL
    begin
        print 'does not exists'
        --uncomment the below line and you will see
        --an error saying table already exists
        --even though the IF was evaluate as TRUE

        --create table #temp (ID datetime)      
    end
else
    begin
        print 'exists'
    end
```

I'm trying to achieve a more complex script but I end up with a problem to verify if a temporary table exists and create it if necessary.

In some part of my code I can have or no a temporary table already created. So I check if it exists and if doesn't exists I want to create it.

The problem is that if I only print the message it evaluates as `exists` but if I uncomment the part where it `does not exists` and create a new one it is avoided to run because it say it already exists.

Why uncommenting `create table #temp (ID datetime)` make SQL run the `true` part of the `IF` statement if it always evaluates as `false`?

I'm running SQL Server 2008 (10.50.2500) in SQL Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Comment: You've assumed that the error is because `by the time the code reaches this point the table will exist`.  It's actually because `at the point in time when you submit the T-SQL (aka Parse Time) the table Currently exists`.

Comment: @MatBailie - it's actually slightly more subtle, if the OP is really running the code shown. At the point at which the T-SQL was submitted, the table didn't exist - the first `IF` block then worked, and it then created a table. When that happens, the remainder of the batch was *re-* compiled, and it's at **that** point, if the second `IF` blocks contents are uncommented, that the compilation error occurs.

Comment: The point is, you can not check for table existence and create it if necessary. Rewrite your query to make sure table is created somewhere upfront outside the IFs. If you need it for different parts of code, just check whatever it's filled and truncate it if needed.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic With `...you can not check for table existence..` you mean it is technically wrong/impossible? And to check if it is filled I need to be sure it exists. I already said that I'm curious about the behavior indeed. I already workarouded it. (that word exists!?)

Comment: @VictorCanova I mean, query is parsed upfront before executing and `IF/ELSE` parts are not taken into account. So if you are creating a #temp table in some part of script it will show error if you try to create it again in other part of script - no matter that two parts are mutually exclusive. What you have experienced maybe looks wrong but is designed behavior.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic +1 for your answer. -1 for using `C` in my name. ;) Just kidding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#temp') IS NOT NULL
    begin
        exec('drop table #temp ')        
    end
go
create table tempdb..#temp (ID datetime)

IF OBJECT_ID('#temp') IS NULL
    begin
        select 'does not exists'

    end
else
    begin
        select 'exists'
    end
```

or

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NULL
    begin
        exec('create table #temp (ID datetime)')        
    end




--I've just created so it should evaluates as False
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NULL
    begin
        print 'does not exists'
        --uncomment the below line and you will see
        --an error saying table already exists
        --even though the IF was evaluate as TRUE

        --create table #temp (ID datetime)      
    end
else
    begin
        print 'exists'
    end
```

Comment: If #temp table is created inside dynamic sql, it will only exists inside same dynamic sql. So second IF will always be 'does not exists'

Comment: No, Table exists during your session. I've removed `tempdb.dbo.` from your condition, maybe it will work.

Comment: Please try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5562 OR http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5563

Comment: Well, `Drop table` will work, even without dynamic SQL, but I don't know if it is OK for OP or he wanted to use data from table if existed.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I've thought you are OP :). We will see is it good for him. But I'm not sure Sql fiddle is good for testing temp table. I left 1st version of my answer.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic You mean drop table with exec? It will not fail if it not exists?

Comment: @Parado Actually you solution is very good. But I will give more context about what I'm really running. I keep the connection opened and ran the same query more than once. So in the first time I sucessfully create the table but in the second it breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Your error occurs at parse time, that is, before the query is actually executed.  Replace this:

```
create table #temp (ID datetime)
```

with:

```
exec('create table #temp (ID datetime)')
```

Since `exec` creates a new scope, the `create table` is only parsed when the temporary table does not exist.